# How to Create a Word.docx Report from a SharePoint 2010 List?

Tags: 2010

I would appreciate some general guidance to point me down the right path. I want to create a monthly Word report where each record in an existing list will appear on their own page in a single Word document, totaling about 40 pages (40 records).

I have a Word template and a limited understanding of how to place the fields on the document from a document library list but not sure where to start building this from my current list.

1. I created a document library and made my Word template the default
   template.  Do I need this library to copy records from my list in
   order to populate the Word fields or can I do it from my current list?
2. Since the list uses the same field names for all records, how do I start the next record on the next page, and so forth?
3. I assume I need a workflow to generate the
   report?

Comment: You say word.doc, is it really doc, or docx? Huge difference when it comes to generating document programmatically.

Comment: It's a docx document

Answer (score 0):

for out of the box with no coding you need to:

1. Do as you did and create your document template as default template to a library.
2. Do NOT use a separate list if possible, it will complicate your setup. Simply add these columns to the library with the document.
3. Inside the document use SmartParts to connect to the column entries in the library.

Now when you open a new document and save it to the library, the contents of the SmartParts will be updated from the word documents.

If you have to keep the 2nd list then I would use a workflow that will create the document in the library and copy over the same data points, so you can continue to work with the SmartParts.

Comment: Hmmm… the current list has 3800 records so I will have work from that instead of a library. I’ll give the workflow a shot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may be able to try linking them via a lookup column in the library - that may work but I have not tried it so not sure if they will be picked up by the SmartParts in word.